# Как создать блок Gutenberg при помощи Carbon Fields на русском?

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg

Когда я пытаюсь создать свой блок и дать ему название кириллицей, то на странице он не отображается вообще. Т.е. в редакторе добавить на страницу и наполнить я его могу, а вот в публичной части его нет.

Прилагаю изображение. Если на месте текста "Some name..." написать что-то на кириллице, тогда и возникает такая проблема.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
Block::make( 'custom-block', 'Кастом блок' )
```

Для переводов:

```
Block::make( 'custom-block', __('Кастом блок', 'your-site-textdomain') )
```